# Why is my imagebutton flipped horizontally and vertically?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an image button defined like this

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnEditWorkDuration"
    android:layout_width="12dp"
    android:layout_height="12dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/edit"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
```

Here's how it looks in the Design tab:

[image: How it looks in design editor]

and here's how it looks in text editor (note the drawable in the margin next to line number 31 is not flipped)

[image]

Why is this happening?

I've moved the offending ImageButton to another layout file, the entire layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="12dp" android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_height="12dp" android:src="@drawable/edit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've uploaded the original image (edit.png) from the resources folder to this url: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=27107676428757093272

My Android Studio version is 2.3.3

Comment: what do you mean it is not flipped?

Comment: In the top image the point of the pencil icon is in the top right. In the bottom image in the margins the point is in the bottom left as it is in the png file.

Comment: Android Studio bug? What does it look like on the emulator/ the device?

Comment: It looks like in the design tab both on the simulator and physical device.

Comment: could you please provide more of your code. i see only one image button here

Comment: Do you see in the second picture line numbers next to line 31 there's an icon of the pencil? Do you see how it's rotated differently from the icon in the top picture?

Comment: I'm afraid we can't do much except agree that the icon has been rotated by 180 degrees if you can't provide us with enough code so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: I've updated my question (at the bottom is the entire layout file where the problem is evident and the URL for the original png image I'm using)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I sure don't know why this happens, but I can confirm that it happens. I'm currently also using Android Studio 2.3.3, so maybe it's a bug which only occurs with this AS version.

The scale type `android:scaleType="centerInside"` should simply

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that
>   both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or
>   less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

(quoted from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html))

But in addition to that, it rotates the drawable by 180 degrees. BTW it happens also with other png files from the material icons library, so there's nothing wrong with your edit.png.

I got rid of the rotation by using `android:scaleType="center"`. But unfortunately this will lead to the icon being clipped, so it's not really a solution to your problem.

Possible workarounds all involve using another image resource so no scaling will be necessary and `android:scaleType="center"` will be sufficient:

- use a vector drawable with size 12dp x 12 dp. You can create one from within Android Studio (New -> Vector Asset...)
- get the material icon zip file for 18dp from Google's [material.io/icons/](https://material.io/icons/) and copy all the png files not into the drawable folder with the same suffix but into the folder with the next resolution level, e.g. -mdpi goes into -hdpi. (As usual, rename the files while copying them so that they all have the same name) This leaves you without a resource for *mdpi*, so get the *hdpi* resource from the zip file and scale it to half its size with your favourite image manipulation program.

Or, of course, you can upgrade to the latest Android Studio version since meanwhile this bug has been fixed.

Comment: `center` messes up the scaling, the small ImageButton doesn't show the entire image unless it's `centerInside`

Comment: @TimSim - you're right, sorry I overlooked that. If you're using material icons then you can create a vector drawable (new vector asset...) in Android Studio and set its dimension to 12 dp x 12 dp. Then "center" will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I am using AS 3.0.1 and I can confirm that I can't reproduce the error. It works fine just using the same code. Maybe a AS bug